# On the possibility and legality of bulk downloading papers from IEEE Xplore

Tags: legal-issues, ieee, online-resource, literature-search

Is it possible to download all available literature from [IEEE Xplore](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/home.jsp)? Is it allowed?

I was thinking that now, while I still have access due to being in academia, I might download everything I could possibly need.

Bonus question: If it is allowed, how do I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not allowed.

[IEEE Xplore terms of use](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplorehelp/#/overview-of-ieee-xplore/legal-information#terms-of-use) (emphasis mine):

> Authorized users are not permitted to:
>
> - Allow anyone other than an authorized user to use or access IEEE Xplore;
> - Display or otherwise make any information from IEEE Xplore available to anyone other than an authorized user;
> - Transmit electronically, via email or any other file transfer protocols, any portion of IEEE Xplore;
> - **Download or attempt to download an entire issue or issues of a publication contained in IEEE Xplore;**
> - Create a searchable archive of any portion of IEEE Xplore;
> - Use robots or intelligent agents to access, search, and/or systematically download any portion of IEEE Xplore;
> - Use any portion of IEEE Xplore for document delivery, fee-for-service use, or bulk reproduction or commercial distribution of materials in any form;
> - Alter or modify any portion of IEEE Xplore;
> - Delete or remove in any form or format, including on a printed article, any copyright information or notice contained in IEEE Xplore;
> - Reproduce or redistribute any portion of IEEE Xplore.

Comment: General remark: if you're an employee or student of a university, then before taking website Ts&Cs from a journal publisher as the final word on what you are, or are not, allowed to do, check whether your university library has a contract with the publisher that supersedes the website Ts&Cs and may be more (or less) permissive.